# setTimeout giving a 'result of expression is not a function' error

Tags: javascript, jquery, settimeout

I have a setTimeout call:

```
if ($cardOne instanceof jQuery){

    setTimeout(function() {
        resetCard($cardOne);
    }, 1000);

    $cardOne = "";
}
```

calling this function:

```
function resetCard($card){
  $card.removeClass('show');
}
```

This results in this error:

Result of expression '$card.removeClass' [undefined] is not a function.

And I am not sure what that means. Is setTimeOut wanting a return value of some sorts? I have verified that $card is, indeed, a jQuery object (in this case a DIV) .

UPDATE:

I added some more example code above to point out what I was doing wrong. Pointy got me to realize that the issue was that $card was not a jQuery object when the removeClass was being called on it.

If you look at my sample code, it's now obvious in hindsight what I was doing wrong...I was calling the function inside a setTimeout and then immediately setting the $cardOne var back into an empty string. So, by the time setTimeout called the function, the var had been reset and no longer a jQuery object.

The fix is to move the setting of the object to an empty string into the resetCard function.

Comment: Are you **sure** that it's a jQuery object, and not just a reference to the `<div>` DOM element?

Comment: Have you tried to display the value of $card in resetCard, what does it display?

Comment: Try `console.dir($card);` from within the resetCard function.

Comment: Well, I'm first testing it as such: if ($card instanceof jQuery){...}. Should that not indicate that it's a jQuery object?

Comment: @DA if it were a jQuery object, then there'd be a "removeClass" function ...

Comment: @Pointy...you got it! You're right...it WASN'T a jQuery object. My logic was: 1) test for logic 2) pass it to a function in a settimeout 3) reset it to null. In hindsight, it's obvious...step 3 executes before the settimeout triggers so by the time it passed the variable, it's been set back to null. 'DOH!. The fix was to move the setting-to-null into the function that gets called in the settimeout.

Comment: @pointy...please make that an answer so I can mark it as correct!

Comment: @DA The easiest way to determine if it's a jQuery instance object or not is to `console.dir()` it. Then you can open up your console and check whether the logged object contains [the properties of a jQuery instance object](http://vidasp.net/jQuery-members.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What happens if you change "resetCard" as follows:

```
function resetCard($card) {
  $($card).removeClass('show');
}
```

The error means that there's no "removeClass" attribute on the object referenced by the "$card" parameter.

Comment: Not the exact answer, but you got me to rethink my logic and you're correct...it wasn't an jQuery object by the time it got passed to the function. I'll update my question to make that clear as to what I was doing wrong.